# Is it possible to target a specific website using Google Adwords?

Tags: advertising, google-ads, ad-targeting

I'm trying to advertise my website to people visiting a specific webpage through google adwords. I know it's possible due to this Google's webpage - https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2497832?hl=en&ref_topic=3119139.

There's the following example:

```
You can use topic targeting in combination with individual placements -- 
which are pages or sites you've chosen where you'd like your ad to show -- 
and keyword targeting -- which lets you choose the keywords that should 
trigger your ad to show.

Example:
You can use topic targeting in combination with individual placements -- 
which are pages or sites you've chosen where you'd like your ad to show -- 
and keyword targeting -- which lets you choose the keywords that should 
trigger your ad to show.
```

However I can't find the option itself. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can target the specific website but it works on Display Network ads campaign only . so if you want to target image or flash related ads you can choose any website that are related to your business.

if you use the display network campaign there is a one option. that is Placements in this placement tag you can specify individual website